# What is the feasibility of a rocket hobbyist achieving a LEO orbit with a microsat?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch, rockets, amateur-rocketry, amateur-radio

Along with being a rocket hobbyist, I'm also an Amateur Radio Operator. I would like to determine the possibility of placing a "microsat" a miniature packet radio satellite, into a low earth orbit.

Comment: Do you mean with your own launch vehicle (completely infeasible) or as a cubesat (very difficult, but not totally impossible)?

Comment: Yes I wish to construct my own launch vehicle using hybrid rocket motors.

Comment: You only need to search within this site to get an understanding of how difficult it is to put something into orbit.

Comment: Plus I'm sure, that only specific flight paths, and orbital paths are available, and of course getting that permission involves the bureaucracy. I'd be gone of old age by that time. Fun to dream though!!

Comment: @G.Ericsson The paperwork is actually the easy part— it doesn’t take a decade and tens of millions of dollars.

Comment: Scott Manley on YouTube: [How Small Can You Make an Orbital Rocket?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1bZO16em2c)

Comment: To launch a microsat into an orbit, you need much more than a micro rocket. You need at least two stages. Even if the payload is very small and light the second stage should be lifted into orbit. But the second stage needs a computerized control unit and batteries for power supply. All structural material necessary for the second stage must be lifted in orbit too. The tanks for propellants are empty when reaching orbit, but the remaining weight of the second stage must be lifted into orbit.

Comment: Here's a nice video on what I'd consider a "very nice, large-scale amateur rocket": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJppeRWSD94 - it's solid fuel, single-stage, and took a smallish team of skilled engineers and a pretty decent budget (I don't think they say how much, but I'd guess something around $100K, not counting tools and expertise). They were just aiming to get enough altitude to film the curvature of the earth. It reached 15km altitude, going straight up.

Comment: [Rocket Lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lab) seems to be nearly as minimal an enterprise as could do this.

Comment: @Beejamin if that's the video I think it is, there is an important fact made there:  no-one has yet managed to get a "hobby" rocket like that into anywhere near orbit.

Comment: @Baldrickk - oh yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say, too (reading my comment back, it's maybe not so clear): a dozen skilled and experienced engineers and rocketry enthusiasts with $100K to spend _gets you nowhere close to orbit_. Really puts the size and difficulty of the task into perspective.

Answer (score 47):

It isn't really feasible to launch your own rocket, unless you have a lot of money to spend. The required power is immense. Hitting sub-orbital might be possible, and has been done once by amateurs, but they received sponsorships and had a team dedicated to making it happen.

The trick to an orbital rocket is not just to get high, but also fast. The speed required is something like 7.4 km/s. That is so fast that I don't think most people understand just how fast it is. During that time one has to control the rocket perfectly. One can play Kerbal Space Program and get an idea of just how difficult that can be, and Kerbal has a number of things that make it easier than real life, like no wind, infinite reaction wheels, etc.

Bottom line, if you have to ask people on the internet if this can be done, then the answer is no. If you are a multi-millionaire (more like tens of millions), or can get ahold of millions, and want to put together a team, then you might be able to do it, but even then only with great effort.

Building a cubesat is somewhat realistic, however, and many have been done by students, including even at least one high school. Once you have it, you can pay around $50K or so to have it launched in to space. Those can operate over amateur frequencies.

Comment: The power requirement is not out of range; the precision engineering requirement is. I looked it up. You're going to need 2.6 tons of aluminum perchlorate fuel and I found it at a dollar a pound on a quick google search. (I was expecting quite a bit higher).

Comment: You would need rocket grade aluminum perchlorate, which is going to be a bit more expensive. Still, it is a very complex process, to say the least! Also, the fuel amount seems a bit low.

Comment: It is enough. http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/ss520.html

Comment: The government is going to take a keen interest when you purchase large quantities of that stuff.

Comment: Note that even to purchase it in large quantities you have to either be a part of an aerospace company, university, or else have a high level rocket license.

Comment: @Nathaniel Agreed, if you're building it. But if you're willing to use existing hardware it seems reasonable; apparently SS-520-5 only needed 500 million yen =~ $4.5 million.

Comment: Falcon 1 was put in to orbit for maybe $100 million, and there are even lower cost launches that have been performed recently. Tens of millions is enough.

Comment: Would it be any more feasible if [the earth were flat](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2018/03/25/an-amateur-rocket-maker-finally-launched-himself-off-earth-now-to-prove-its-flat/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.ad51fd9ca006)? I guess if you only want to go straight up 52 miles without achieving orbital velocity, that's probably easier.

Comment: The Falcon 9 can lift 28,990 lbs into LEO. The cube satellite will be closer to 1-2 lbs. Using the cost to launch a Falcon to calculate the cost of launching a cube is ridiculous. You might as well compare it to the NASA Space Launch System or the Saturn V.

Answer (score 13):

Developing, testing and launching a rocket are very complex tasks, and generally require years of development. Some examples of the smallest orbit launchers would be the recently tested [Electron, by RocketLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(rocket)), and the [SS-520, by the Japanese Space Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Series_(rocket_family)). The first one has 17 meters of height and 1.2 meters in diameter, and the second 9.7 meters in height and 0.5 meters in diameter. Of course both of them required the investment of tens of millions of dollars for their development.

In 2008, a Cambridge professor launched a competition called the [N-Prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Prize), where the objective was to launch between 10 to 20 grams of payload into orbit, developing the satellite and the launcher spending less than £999. So far, nobody has completed the challenge.

Your best option, like the other small sats, would be to piggyback a typical rocket launch, using a CubeSat/Microsat deployment system. Several companies sell these services, e.g. [GAUSS Team](https://www.gaussteam.com) and [Spaceflight Industries](http://spaceflight.com).

From an energy perspective, if you want to place 10 kg into LEO (250 km), you need to provide [roughly 9.4 km/s of Delta-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget#Launch/landing). This gives a 0.90 propellant ratio, using the optimistic value 400 seconds of specific impulse. In other words, it would be a very difficult construction, considering the development of light structures, cryogenics, etc.

Comment: @NickT The linked wiki article lists the requirement as under £999.99

Answer (score 5):

It's probably good to bring up [Copenhagen Suborbital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_Suborbitals) up as a reference here. They're quite possibly the most competent amateur rocketeers, yet their name already points out that they're not aiming for orbit.

In general, the challenge point for amateurs currently is the Karman line, 100 km up and the official start of space, but that is a whole lot easier than orbital speeds.

Answer (score 2):

**G. Ericsson could potentially get a cube satellite into Low Earth Orbit for under $100,000.00.**

[image: Vector-R Rocket]

Vector is a nano-satellite launch company creating rockets targeted towards launching small payloads into Low Earth Orbit (LEO). They are taking reservations to reserve space on five orbital launch rockets between 2019 and 2023 on the Vector-R launch vehicle. They have not yet put a rocket into LEO, so this is speculative, but they seem to have a very firm strategy.

Their rocket, the Vector-R (Vector Rapid) rocket is two-stage orbital expendable launch vehicle developed to cover the commercial small satellite launch segment. In other words, they launch cube satellites.

Vector completed a test flight of their rocket at low altitude (not LEO)  in May 2017. Vector is  planning the first orbital launch from the Pacific Spaceport Complex in Kodiak, AK later in July, 2018. They have secured launch platforms at Vandenberg, CA and Wallops Island, VA.

The Vector-R can launch a modest 140 lb payload into LEO for a modest sum of under 3 million dollars. The actual price has been listed to as low as 1.5 million to 3 million. If @G. Ericsson were to pool his resources with around 25 other cubesat people with a five lb maximum payload, the cost would be around $95,000 per cubesat. All of these figures were rounded down to even numbers to make things easy.

Good luck with your future LEO walkie-talkie.

**More Information**:

- https://vector-launch.com/vector-r/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector-R
- http://www.spaceflightinsider.com/missions/commercial/space-florida-vector-r-ing-new-launch-provider-cape-canaveral/

Comment: It would be good to be clearer that all of this is what Vector are aiming to do (and the prices they're aiming to charge). So far they have only done low altitude suborbital launches.

Comment: @djr, I edited my answer and made it clear they have not yet sent a rocket to LEO. I posted this listing the potential for a cubesat and an alternative to paying $80 million for a Falcon Heavy rocket launch which would be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Since 1961, there have been a series of satellites called OSCAR, for Orbiting Satellite Carrying Amateur Radio. These have generally been launched when some other space mission has excess lifting capacity.

As far as I know, if you are going to launch something into space which will transmit radio, you need to get the approval of appropriate government agencies, such as the FCC in the United States.